# extjs4 files cannot been loaded

Tags: spring-mvc, extjs4

I'm using extjs4 and spring mvc (Java EE).

when I run project I can't see anything on browser.

I add this code on my servlet dispatcher:

```
 <mvc:annotation-driven />
 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

And when I run it this is the error shown:

```
28 avr. 2013 21:15:30 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
ATTENTION: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/CR/application/view/Viewport.js] 
in DispatcherServlet       with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
28 avr. 2013 21:15:30 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
ATTENTION: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/CR/Ext4Example/view/login/LoginForm.js] 
in    DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
```

Ext4Example is the name of my extjs application 
and this is my app.js

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled: true});

Ext.application({
name: 'Ext4Example',
appFolder: 'application',

controllers: [
   'Login'
],
autoCreateViewport: true
});
```

and this my index.jsp page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>

<!-- Ext JS Files -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/ext-4.0/resources/css/ext-all.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources//css/main.css"/>
 <script src="./resources/ext-4.0/ext-all.js"></script>



 <!-- App Files -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./resources/application/app.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="./resources/application/view/Viewport.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="./resources/application/view/login/CenterPanel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./resources/application/view/login/create-rd.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="./resources/application/view/login/HomePage.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="./resources/application/view/login/LoginForm.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="./resources/application/view/login/WestMenu.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="./resources/application/controller/Login.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="./resources/application/model/Login.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="./resources/application/store/Login.js"></script>



</head>
<body background="./resources/images/gray.jpg">

</body>
</html>
```

Can any one explain the error to me?

When I click Ctrl+U and I click on the files URL I can see the code source.

Answer (score 0):

And what if you use the spring tag? Something like that :

```html
<spring:url value="/resources/application/view/Viewport.js" var="some_url"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${some_url}"></script>
```

Comment: i fix it by using this:
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='<c:url   value="/resources/application/app.js"/>'></script>